# Avoid late reponse after clicking the button in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

When I click the button, the button turns red and it reads some input data and display the output data on the label. It functions well but when I read the data back, there is a long delay(about 0.5 sec) after the button turns red.  What kind of strategy that I could do to reduce the long delay?
Thanks

Comment: What button? Post your code. Read the following article, edit your question accordingly, and you'll get much better replies: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Apparently there is some code involved in turning it red and back again.  I suspect the problem is there.

Comment: You say this is vb.net, so when the user clicks the button, the data has to go to the server and come back, so 0.5 seconds doesn't sound very bad; I wouldn't qualify that as a 'long delay' unless the button isn't supposed to do anything other than turn red or some other simple client-side calculation. What processing is done by the button and how long do you expect it to take?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should avoid using the same thread for UI and data pull.

Try doing an async call to the "pulling" of the data.

Comment: multi-threading?? Well, I use backgroundworker to make the performance a LITTLE bit better